# geom_polygon fill based on values from multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a R plot of the following sort

```
regionalPlot <- ggplot(data = analyzed) + 
                geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = income, group = group), color = "white") + 
                coord_fixed(1.3) +
                theme_bw()
```

The plot is generated by plotting the longitude and latitudes of a certain region grouped by the region name, and the region is being filled by some data value for that region (say `income`). This value is provided to the fill attribute as well for `geom_polygon` as `fill=value`.

However, I have 2 extra conditioning parameters say `state_tax` and `sales_tax`, both of which have `true/false` values.
I want to fill the polygons using the same values, but by choosing a color scale based on the two conditioning parameters.
So here I'll have 4 such combinations

```
state_tax == 'true' and sales_tax == 'true'
state_tax == 'true' and sales_tax == 'false'
state_tax == 'false' and sales_tax == 'true'
state_tax == 'false' and sales_tax == 'false'
```

Essentially I am looking for a way such that all states with a the same combination of values for state and sales tax, should be colored in different shades of same color interpolated by the value of income.

Can anybody point me to a way which would allow me to do this?
Let me know in the comments if more information is needed.

Comment: Can you post your data?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ayenpure/330fea57029796d28b51ece41021032f

This is the data I am working with, the fields mentioned in the question had been modified to present a simpler usecase, but here
`income -> value` and `state_tax/sales_tax -> over_mean, over_standard`

I use this data and perform an inner join on `region` with the states data sourced using instructions  from this link http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how you can post an R question that is easy for folks to help with. That includes the data we would need to work with and *all* your code being in the post, not as links